# find_package error while installing iai_photo

Tags: ros, find-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install [iai_photo](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_photo) package.  I have already installed gphoto2 and libgphoto2 libraries and got it working with a sony camera.

Further I git cloned the [iai_photo](https://github.com/code-iai/iai_photo) package and tried to catkin_make it. But I get the following error

> CMake Error at
> iai_photo-master/CMakeLists.txt:17
> (find_package):   By not providing
> "FindGPHOTO2.cmake" in
> CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
> asked CMake to find a package
> configuration file provided by
> "GPHOTO2", but   CMake did not find
> one.
>
> Could not find a package
> configuration file provided by
> "GPHOTO2" with any   of the following
> names:
>
> ```
> GPHOTO2Config.cmake
> gphoto2-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of
> "GPHOTO2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
> "GPHOTO2_DIR" to a directory
> containing one of the above files.  If
> "GPHOTO2" provides a separate
> development package or SDK, be sure it
> has   been installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271928/find_package-error-while-installing-iai_photo/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your answer. I already found the problem. The error was because of wrong name of package folder

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0